# How to handle a java call to a dll that ocassionaly throws EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have coded a Java application that through JNI calls a linear programming solver written in C++. After a number of successful calls I get an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error and the application terminates. 
How can I dismiss the error and keep the Java application operating?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if a dll crashes then the JVM will terminate.

This is one of the drawbacks of using JNI in the first place. So it is generally not as simple as *swallowing* some exception from the dll.

In your case the error hints towards unitialized memory. You should look towards out of bound indexing in your code.

You should post your code though in order to get more help

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep JVM running if there is access violation happened in native code.

There are several things you can do.

- Best - carefully debug your lib without JNI, with small standalone C++ client, and find the reason of this violation, and add excessive checks around that (incorrect pointer usage, incorrect memory cleanup etc)
- Run your DLL in a separate JVM process, which is purely responsible for providing this solver functionality, communicate with second JVM using sockets, tcp-ip, soap, rest - whatever you prefer. Than, use some like Java Service Wrapper to run this second JVM and configure it in the way that it restarts the JVM if it crashed.